# Extending a Jenkins/Hudson plugin to set a environment variable pair

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins, hudson, environment-variables

I am extending an existing Jenkins/Hudson plugin. I would like it to set a environment variable pair for the running project. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

During build, for example in a `Builder`'s `perform()` method, you can do at least this:

```
@Override
public boolean perform(Build<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)
                       throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    //...
    List<ParameterValue> params = new ArrayList<ParameterValue>();
    params.add(new StringParameterValue(name1, value1));
    params.add(new StringParameterValue(name2, value2));
    build.addAction(new ParametersAction(params));
    //...
}
```

It will add the key-value pairs as build parameters, which will be visible as environment variables too, in the usual manner. Note: I have not tested that extensively, there may be some "gotcha" which presents itself in some situation... But it has worked for me so far.

Comment: Good! You can also make your own action which implements `InvisibleAction` in the case you don't want your parameters to appear on your job page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.  You can create the environment variables prior to the job starting, or do it as a build step.

Comment: I guess, I haven't expressed myself clearly. I need my extended plugin to save some information about its status as an env variable. So I need a generic Jenkins solution (code) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EnvironmentContributor extension point, see http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/EnvironmentContributor.html